# Understanding UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

Tags: ios, uikit, drawing, core-graphics, uigraphicscontext

I'm trying to understand Quartz and getting the context you have to draw on.  If I have a function where I create a context, but then I call another function to some other drawing to the same context, do I need to pass the context from the first method to the next?  Or can I just use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` for any CG methods that require a context since I'm still drawing into the same context?

Answer (score 16):

The [docs for UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623918-uigraphicsgetcurrentcontext) say:

> The current graphics context is nil by default. Prior to calling its
>   drawRect: method, view objects push a valid context onto the stack,
>   making it current. If you are not using a UIView object to do your
>   drawing, however, you must push a valid context onto the stack
>   manually using the `UIGraphicsPushContext(_:)` function.

So after calling `UIGraphicsPushContext()` with the context you've created, your other methods can access that context with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`. If you're calling `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` outside of drawRect: and haven't set a context explicitly with `UIGraphicsPushContext()`, the current graphics context is undefined—and certainly not safe to use.

Comment: here's a working link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623918-uigraphicsgetcurrentcontext